# some doubts related to osgi

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

I am new to OSGI framework. I was going through the sites and read about OSGI framework. Frankly speaking I did notunderstand anything. Following are my doubts

1. OSGi is supposed to provide modularity.  Cant we  achieve the modularity through normal jars?
2. What does it mean that OSGi has a *dynamic* component model?
3. Bundles can be installed,started,stopped,updated,etc. Why do we want to install the bundles? Why cant we access directly like what we access other normal jars?

I am totally confused. Can somebody answer me ? If it is possible to give some examples also.

Comment: I promise I'm not trying to be snarky, but the features offered by OSGi kind of only make sense in the context of best practice Java archiecture. OSGi is a kind of power tool for building really well architected Java apps.  Without that goal and set of imperitives, the modularity, component lifecycle and "SOA in a JVM" concepts aren't much to look at.

Comment: @chad: I think you did very well there - not snarky at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to answer you first question in the OSGi blog: http://blog.osgi.org/2013/08/dear-prudence-cant-we-achieve.html

Next week, will answer the next.

Answer (score 4):

1. No. JARs are open containers for classes and provide no runtime encapsulation. See http://www.slideshare.net/bjhargrave/why-osgi
2. Dynamic means that a bundle's lifecycle can be altered while the VM/OSGi framework is running. That is, you don't need to restart the system to install/start/stop/update/uninstall a bundle.
3. You want to do those things to manage the lifecycle of the bundles. One does not have to use OSGi in a dynamic way. You can just use it for modularity and services while only installing the bundles up front before starting the framework.

Answer (score 4):

My definition of a module is a *unit of encapsulation* (i.e. it hides internal details) that communicates with other modules via a *contract* (i.e. a predefined set of possible interactions). A JAR file is not a module because it exhibits neither of these properties. There is no encapsulation, all internal implementation details are visible and accessible from the outside. There is no contract, you just put the JAR file on the classpath and hope it provides the features you desire.

Dynamic means that OSGi bundles (modules) can be installed, upgraded or uninstalled *during runtime*. This can be very useful for upgrading running systems or for deploying software to a efficiently across a large network.

Bundles have to be installed because software always has to be installed before we use it. JAR files also have to be installed! Only the means of installation is slightly different, i.e. JAR files are added to the classpath whereas bundles are installed using the `install` command (this can also be scripted or called from an API). OSGi gives us much more control over this process.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the aspect of Bundles as true modules, which has been dealt with in all the other answers, there are several other features that make OSGi extremely powerful:

1. The **service-layer** enables you to dynamically wire your *objects* at runtime. Combined with [declarative services](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services) you get a very powerful and flexible programming-model with all the benefits of [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).
2. The [**Extender Model**](http://blog.osgi.org/2007/02/osgi-extender-model.html) provides a kind of IOC on a higher level, and can create huge benefits for extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

It might be advantageous to read about an implementation of the OSGi specification.

If you have used Eclipse, then you have experienced some of the advantages of OSGi and may not even known it.

Here's a great description of the basics of what Equinox is.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html